# Characteristic of LEDs

Tags: led, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I measured with an oscilloscope the characteristic of three LEDs (green, red and yellow) connected in series with a 1000 Ohm resistor. The result of the measurement was this figure:

[image]

Why do I have negative currents?

This has been troublesome because I cannot fit the Shockley diode equation.

Is there any other equation that might be useful to fit the data?

I appreciate your help.

PS. I also measured that day the characteristic of a Zener diode, and also got negative currents.

Comment: Why measure with an oscilloscope?  They are not very accurate.  Any negative currents are probably due to offset error in the scope.  You should use a DVM.

Comment: @KevinWhite, I had no other instrument at the time. So if this is an offset, is it normal that it affects more the red led than the yellow or green leds? In other words, why are the currents from the red led more negative than the currents from the other 2 leds?

Comment: Another thing to be careful about when measuring LEDs is that they are light sensitive but that would not affect the measurements of the zener diode that you said also give negative results.  Did you retest the red LED.  What if you don't connect anything to the scope?

Comment: @KevinWhite Didn't check that :(

Comment: @KevinWhite: Zener diodes are light-sensitive, too, and many of them are in glass packages. All of these measurements must be made with the diodes enclosed in a dark box.

Comment: How did you measure current?  When connected in series as you did, the current must be the same in every LED.

Comment: The voltages on the red and yellow should be about 2volts and the green 3v.  The green voltage would never be less than red or yellow.

Comment: show a schematic diagram of your test setup, and describe the test procedure.  If the voltage is supposed to be the forward voltage across the LED, something is very wrong, as red and yellow LEDs have a lower forward voltage than green (green looks about right, but red should be about 1.8 volts.)

Comment: If the red and yellow LEDs are "5 volt LEDs", rather than bare LEDs, they will have an internal current limiting circuit, which would explain their higher voltage, and constant voltage with change in current.